# How to make the background also resizeable

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.resizeable = (True, True)

Background_Color = '#000000'

canvas = Canvas(window, bg=Background_Color)
canvas.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `fill=BOTH` and `expand=True` in the `pack` function parameters.

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.resizeable = (True, True)

Background_Color = '#000000'

canvas = Canvas(window, bg=Background_Color)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)

window.mainloop()
```

You can change `fill=BOTH`(Resize to both axis.) to

1. `fill=X`(Only resize the canvas to the x-axis)
2. or `fill=Y`(ONly resize the canvas to the y-axis).